# How do I use the .htaccess file to rewrite a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I have a question relating to re-writing URL's using the `.htaccess` file.

I don't really understand the symbols and syntax for writing what I require for the htaccess file so I would really appreciate any help please.

**SYSTEM INFORMATION**
Joomla 2.5.9 website
I use K2  2.6.2 for creating my content
When I create content for my blog using K2 I complete the 'Title alias (URL)'

**HTACCESS QUERY**
As an example I have written an article called Top 10 Joomla Extensions 
The title alias URL is: top-10-joomla-extensions

When I view the article at the front end the URL is:
http://www.pixelfire.com.au/website-and-graphic-design-blog/**item/121-**top-10-joomla-extensions

I would like to clean up this URL by removing: **item/121-**
I have many other item URL's with different ID numbers I'd like to remove too. So the code I require needs to remove the ID number for every item in my Blog.

Each blog item URL has the words item/item ID number. Example item/121-
Ideally I would like to remove the word item and the item number with the dash.

Hopefully someone can help me write the `.htaccess` code to achieve this and explain to me how it works.

Thank you very much in advance.
Neil.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)item/(\d+\-)?(.*) /$1$3 [R=301,L]
```

RewriteRule works as follows:
Anything after "RewriteRule" and before the `Space` is our rule,
Anything after said `Space`, is what to do

so: 
`RewriteEngine On` turn on the engine

`RewriteRule` tells apache, to start the magic.
The rest is a regex declaration.

`^` - start at begining of the string
`(.*)` - get anything you desire and place it into variable `$1`
`item/(\d\-)?` - make sure the string `item/` followed by digits and dash exists, but doesn't have to. Make sure it occupies the `$2` variable. The questionmark says "might be there, but doesn't have to".
`(.*)` - get anything that follows, and store it inside the variable `$3`

Then you say, redirect into:
`$1$3` which concatinates the strings stored in variables `$1` and `$3` (skipping item/887878-)

Finally the brackets. `R=301` means, rewirte with 301 header
And `L` says: this is the last thing you need to do. Stop here and reload.

Comment: it's a good answer, but I don't think it's what he needs, since all url's will still be generated/displayed the old way, only they will be redirected. unfortunately the solution for this in joomla is not so simple

Comment: You're right. However, due to 301, google will identify the correct url. So event though it doesn't do the trick, it is a "walkaround". I agree the link generation needs to be done via Joomla configs.

Comment: Hi Unamata,

Thank you very much for your reply and explanation. I now understand what your working is try to do. 

I tried the code you sent through and it doesn't change the URL unfortunately. Perhaps I am missing some small syntax? Or do I need to change the code you have sent through?

Thank you very much for your help and time on this.

Neil.

Comment: @NeilForrester I suggest you see the [sh404sef](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) user1911216 writes about, seems like a good extension. But if you do choose to go manually inside htaccess, then the above should work just fine, however there might be other rules inside your .htaccess file that override it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install a sef component such as sh404sef or joomsef which overrides joomla´s default router and gives you more configuration options